# React: I have an api fetch and the data stores into my hook state. Why can I console.log the hook object, but not access it?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch

I have two other useEffects in my code that fetch data, update a state hook, and allow access to all data properly in other components/same component.

I have one useEffect, however, that's grabbing data from an api fetch that uses an authorization header. I've done this before, with no issue, but on the one in question, it gets the data, updates my state hook, and I can even console.log it out in another component, but the moment I try to do something with it, it gives me an error.

UseEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
const claimStudents = async() => {
  const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/TaughtStudents";
  const result = await axios(url, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
    }
  })
  getState.updateClaimedStudents(result.data)
}
claimStudents()
}, [])
```

Error:

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA8fs.png)

Component that is calling my state data:

```
function ClaimedStudents() {

const getState = useContext(UserContext)

console.log(getState.claimedStudents)

return (
<Card>
  <Card.Text>
   
  </Card.Text>
</Card>
);
}

export default ClaimedStudents;
```

Console log that shows my data loading, though with a delay:

[Console.log showing data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjTml.png)

I know it's something to do with promises and/or the data not delivering in the right time, but I have had little luck googling this issue for an answer.

Any insight or points in the right direction of where I can help fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post your actual code, not pictures of your code

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add a request status observable, like isLoadingStudents, it should be true while fetching the data and false otherwise, then add a spinner or something in the component if the isLoadingStudents is true.

```
if (isLoadingStudents) {
   return <Spinner/>
}
```

Comment: I had to look up what observables were, but I did this instead to test:

Axios.request({
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
    },
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/TaughtStudents',
    responseType: 'json'
  })
    .subscribe(response => {
      getState.updateClaimedStudents(response.data)
    })

Which, again, works on getting the data, and updating my hook state, but then the exact moment I try to access a property of the newly updated hook, it tells me cannot read property xyz of undefined.

Comment: your hook is working fine, that is not the problem.
your problem is in the first render of your component, your data ( claimedStudents ) wasn't available yet as the request was still loading. 
1 - in the user context add a state call it isLoadingStudentsand intialize it with false,
update it with true before fetching the data ( calling axios ) and update it false after getting the data. -- before and after the line const result = await axios... --
2 - in your component do the condition i wrote to you in the beginning 
if ( getState.isLoadingStudents ) {} and put it before your main return

Comment: Okay, so I tried that. It works in terms of getting the spinner to show up if it's not loaded yet, but I still run into the same issue. Here's an interesting thing I just found out, though... If I do this:

return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <div>
          {getState.claimedStudents[1].name}
        </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );

It actually gives the name of something, but if I try to map through the thing it still says it's undefine.

Comment: Delayed thank you for responding, by the way, even if I did have a duh moment on the why hahaha

Answer (score 0):

Or you can directly go with this:

**Warning: You cannot do custom error handling**

```
 getState? (
   getState.claimstudent.map(({student}=>{
     <li> {student} </li>
    }))
 ):(
   <Loader />
 )
```

Comment: Oh sorry then its whatever your data is labelled by not getState

Comment: I assume this is meant to render the list items if there's something accesible in the hook, otherwise, load a loader. I tried this, and my test page still renders, but now I get:
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>.

Comment: It's fine. I had to remember ternary when i was testing this hah

Comment: Oh, okay, so the inside a p thing was fixed when I got rid of the Card component, but now I jsut get a spinner. That makes the page load, but will it ever make the data be accesible?

Comment: like if you don't remove `getState.map()` what is the error you get is it the same undefined error or something else, if yes edit the question and put that up, if no then there is a problem with your data (the format of it)

Comment: So funny story. I didn't put the right thing in useState(). Now I have it no longer being unable to map, but it's still not putting data to where I can access it. I'll have to investigate this further and if I can't figure that out, I'll ask another question. Thank you for your responses. It did help me recollect things!

Answer (score 0):

So turns out I was a goof and did the wrong thing inside my useState() hook. Whoops me. It didn't fix my data being not accessible 100%, but I'm no longer getting the error.